# Remove first from multiple duplicate rows in spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a DataFrame something similar to this

```
+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----+
    |     disc_created_dt|    disc_modified_dt|        disc_line_id|         quarter_num|         period_year|          start_date|            end_date| test|
    +--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----+
    |2012-05-31 10:50:...|2016-03-12 10:41:...|138371.0000000000...|4.000000000000000000|2012.000000000000...|2012-05-27 09:30:...|2012-06-23 09:30:...|42012|
    |2011-09-27 03:40:...|2016-03-12 10:39:...|141773.0000000000...|1.000000000000000000|2012.000000000000...|2011-09-25 09:30:...|2011-10-29 09:30:...|12012|
    |2011-06-22 02:41:...|2016-03-12 10:40:...|59374.00000000000...|4.000000000000000000|2011.000000000000...|2011-05-29 09:30:...|2011-06-25 09:30:...|42011|
    |2012-02-24 23:46:...|2016-03-12 10:39:...|272176.0000000000...|3.000000000000000000|2012.000000000000...|2012-01-29 10:30:...|2012-02-25 10:30:...|32012|
    |2012-09-16 15:02:...|2016-03-12 10:42:...|450778.0000000000...|1.000000000000000000|2013.000000000000...|2012-08-26 09:30:...|2012-09-22 09:30:...|12013|
    +--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-----+
```

`disc_line_id` can have duplicate values. 
There are 2 requirements:

1. I want only 1 record per `disc_line_id` based on `created_date` that I did using dropDuplicates command.
2. I want all records except first based on `modified_date` for a `disc_line_id`

If both can be done in single transformation it would be great.

Example

```
disc_line_id|created_date|modified_date
1             2016-08-24  2016-08-24
1             2016-08-21  2016-08-21
1             2016-08-21  2016-08-24
2             2016-08-23  2016-08-24
3             2016-08-22  2016-08-22
3             2016-08-22  2016-08-23
3             2016-08-22  2016-08-24
```

For following dataframe I want

Req 1 (each disc line id based on created date):

```
 disc_line_id|created_date|modified_date
    1             2016-08-21  2016-08-21
    2             2016-08-23  2016-08-24
    3             2016-08-22  2016-08-22
```

Req 2 (each disc line id based on modified date):

```
 disc_line_id|created_date|modified_date
    1             2016-08-24  2016-08-24
    1             2016-08-21  2016-08-24
    3             2016-08-22  2016-08-23
    3             2016-08-22  2016-08-24
```

I am newbie to spark and scala any help will be appreciated. spark version 1.4.1

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you wish.. could you please give an example of the output you want?

Comment: @shakedzy Added example

Comment: first `modified_date` in Req1 should be `2016-08-24` right? Also, I don't understand what you're doing in Req2.. why were these lines omitted?

Comment: No in Req 1 I am taking oldest created dates. and in Req 2 I am taking all rows which have duplicates except the first created one

Answer (score 1):

Due to lack of subqueries, you have to break it down into several steps.

first you need to select line id and max date (if you want the newest). Do it something like this (assuming your data are in a data frame named `df`)

```
val tmp = df.select("disk_line_id","created_date").groupBy("disk_line_id").max("created_date").withColumnRenamed("disk_line_id", "line_id")
val theNewest = tmp.join(df,tmp("max(created_date)")===df("created_date") && tmp("line_id")===df("disk_line_id")).drop("max(created_date)").drop("line_id")
```

then in order to get everything *except* the newest:

```
val theRest = df.except(theNewest)
```

the above code is semi pseudo code, as I can't remember if Spark allows you to do `max()` on a date. You might need to convert your dates to timestamps in order to execute the code above.